# roksprocket disable article tags

Tags: plugin

I am using roksprocket as a simple to use filter system of articles.
Sadly I could not find a way to disable the badly looking tags underneath the modules itself.
Of course there is a possible to use CSS with

```
display: none;
```

but is that the only way for roksprocket?

an example of the issue can be found in this [free UML tool article](https://www.xenovation.com/blog/development/java/java-professional-developer/free-uml-tool-for-developers)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

I did not check if there is a possibility to override the roksproket layouts **in the template manager**, since I do not use roksproket, but you can find the **tags part of the mosaic theme layout** here:

in `yourjoomla/com_roksproket/layouts/mosaic/themes/default` folder in `item.php` file.

If you open that file and `// comment out` the lines **from line 59 to 67** then the tags will not show up anymore in your mosaic item layout on your pages.

So this part of the code has to be commented out/overriden or deleted:

***We do not need the ugly tags here:***

```
<?php if (count($item->custom_tags_list)) : ?>
    <ul class="sprocket-mosaic-tags">
    <?php
        foreach($item->custom_tags_list as $key => $name){
            echo ' <li class="sprocket-tags-'.$key.'">'.$name.'</li>';
            }
    ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This action does not influence the tags on any other parts or layouts of the sites, only where these mosaics are displayed.

I hope this can be in help of you.

Comment: thx! do you have me a hint about the template manager? Do not know what you exactly mean?

Comment: @laendle - The Joomla template manager is at extensions->templates->templates->yourtemplate. There you can find the template file editor of Jomla and the Create overrides tab too. (This place usually called "Joomla template manager".

Comment: @laendle - have you used the above solution successfully? Have you managed to clear the layout from the ugly tags in this module?

Comment: sadly I did not had luck, updating your post also, since the folder was not fully defined. I even could not see where the <li> have not been generated. Also adding some additional text was not traced out (in uncommented variant of course)

Comment: @laendle - I do not fully understand your issue, but what I wrote in my answer is that you just have to comment out the code part what I gave you in my answer, exactly in that file and folder that I gave full path to. And it’s done.

Comment: @laendle - more over, if you want to overrdide that layout, you should find that module layout file in the template manager and you should just make an override copy for that there. I here cannot teach you how to do that because that’s another question and you can learn template overrides from joomla documentation. I did not know that you do not know how these work, I’m sorry.

Comment: found my issue. I have overseen the multiple php tags and tried to comment a block like you mentioned it, but this does not work. Works now fine! thank you